# make bash function context aware to list files from folder where it's called

Tags: bash, autocomplete, function

As an alias can not be used to send parameters I have created a function in my .bashrc
Just for the sake of the example calling chemacs script to keep different emacs distributions side by side. The function calls a profile and I want to send a file as parameter. The file autocompletion gives me only the files from the folder Iḿ calling the function from.

```bsh
myemacs() {
    file=$1
    emacs $file --with-profile default
}
```

The issue is autocomplete is listing ALL files from root folder instead the 4 files from the folder I'm calling the function. This makes this funcion almost unusable as i have to write the complete path to my file

```
 $ pwd
 /home/joe/Documents/scripts

 $ myemacs 
 do you wish to see all 5062 possibilities (1688 lines)?
```

Comment: Presumably you've hit `TAB` after `myemacs` (and space)?  Also, your question mentions a "chemacs" while the function is named "myemacs" -- could you elaborate or correct that?

Comment: Chemacs is a github project that replaces emacs call adding profiles, so the command is 'emacs', same as always. Just an example. use any other command that need filenames in context (ls, grep...).